# Processing XML in ASP pages

Tags: xml, asp-classic

Folks....Probably a simple question, but I have not been able to find the simple answer.  Assume the following XML structure is being analyzed in an ASP or ASPx page.

```
<level1>
<Block1>
 <codes>
    <a>XS</a>
    <b>SM</b>
    <c>M</c>
    <d>L</d>
    <e>XL</e>
 </codes>
</Block1>
<Block2>
 <codes>
    <a>XP</a>
    <b>P</b>
    <c>M</c>
    <d>G</d>
    <e>XG</e>
 </codes>
</Block2>
</level1>
```

Now, I can and I have used VBS code like 
    `For each L2Element in L1.Childnodes...` 
to iterate through the levels, blocks and the codes. However, if I really only interested in getting the text for the tag `<c> in <Block2>`, Is there a simple method which I can use to get it directly without iterating through all levels, blocks and codes?

Thanks....RDK

Comment: In my experience the best way to handle xml in Classic ASP is to do an XSL transformation and let your xsl stylesheet do all the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath to query the node you want.

```
Dim xmlDoc : Set xmlDoc = [your xml document here]
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
```

Then, you can select the node you want as follows:

```
Dim oNode    
Set oNode = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//Block2/codes/c")
```

You can then retrieve the value from `oNode`. Don't forget to check if it is `Nothing` first, though. oNode will be equal to `Nothing` if the XPath query didn't find it's target.

In the event that you want to select multiple nodes, there is also a `selectNodes()` method with which you can also use XPath. It will return a collection of nodes, that has a `length` property that you can use for iterating through them. Access each node of the collection with `item(index)`.

Comment: OK, Thanks.  Now how would you do that if <Block1> was changed to <Block Label="one"1>...</Block>  and <Block2> was changed to <Block Label="two">....</Block>?

Comment: I believe it would be `"//Block[@Label='one']/codes/c"` and `"//Block[@Label='two']/codes/c"`. Please, if you have any other questions, mark this answer correct, and open a new Stack Overflow question for help.